# How to compute object properties in object literal based on other properties

Tags: javascript

I'm doing to subtract inside the json is this possible?

```
 @employees = [
{
  "name": "Fullname1"
  "vl": "Vacation Leave",
  "vl_days": "15.0",
  "sl": "Sick Leave",
  "sl_days": "10.0",
  "bday": "Birthday",
  "b_day":"1.0",
  "credit_vl":"12.0",
  "use_vl": "vl_days - credit_vl"
}
```

Comment: [Adding and Subtracting with Javascript and JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220301/adding-and-subtracting-with-javascript-and-json)

Comment: no it is not possible ... because 1) `use_v1` will be a string and 2) you don't have json there, you have a javascript object, 3) the var `@employees` is not a valid javascript object name, as `@` is not a legal character in a javascript object and 4) you forgot the closing `]` ... so all in all, no chance at all

Comment: 5) no comma after `"name": "Fullname1"`

Comment: Congratulations, you have won the prize for the most number of typos in a single post.

Comment: I don't think 5 comes close - maybe today's prize :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am assuming `]`in your question . without this it is not possible.

```js
 employees = [
{
  "name": "Fullname1",
  "vl": "Vacation Leave",
  "vl_days": "15.0",
  "sl": "Sick Leave",
  "sl_days": "10.0",
  "bday": "Birthday",
  "b_day":"1.0",
  "credit_vl":"12.0"
}];
var use_vl=(employees[0].vl_days-employees[0].credit_vl);
 employees[0].use_vl=use_vl;

console.log(employees);
```

Comment: a better (in my opinion) solution would be https://jsfiddle.net/p10rfz1h/

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks . that's a good inline solution. without using new variable

Comment: and it also allows for the array of employees to have more than one element :p

Comment: i know you love map method